# ConflictingBeanDefinitionException when importing configurations from two different packages

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I have a Gradle project that imports two other projects that have the JacksonConfig class containing the definition of the ObjectMapper bean. Those two packages are called:

- common
- gateway-common

All the microservices in my project are using the JacksonConfig class
from the common package but the gateways that import both packages
produce the exception above. Is there a way to apply the
configuration from the gateway-common package and not import the one
from the common package basically, exclude it?

This is how I import them in the build.gradle file

```
testCompile(project(':gateway-common').sourceSets.test.output)
testCompile(project(':common').sourceSets.test.output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html#sec:excluding-transitive-deps

Also, you can use some qualifiers such as Qualifier, Primary, Conditional ...